# Raw Salmon on a green cutting ( RTE ) board

Tags: food-safety

Is this legit ok? My bosses tell me it doesn't matter because the board is going to get washed, when I say there's colors because the dish machine might not get to 165 from time to time and bacteria can be on the RTE cutting board.

[image]

Comment: Ah, the next installment in this kitchen saga - will we get to know where this place is?

Comment: I think this might be an okay safety question, thanks. Let's please avoid further side discussion in the comments, though. You can use the [chat room created off one of your previous posts for that](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57627/discussion-on-answer-by-gdd-can-raw-chicken-share-a-top-loading-cooler-next-to-r) if you wish.

Comment: That does RTE stand for?

Comment: Ready to Eat (I believe)

Comment: Why does your boss make a point? Why not 'just' take the correct board?

Comment: Ah, if you had been watching you will know that this guy/lass is front of house, not necessarily kitchen staff.  It seems that the guys in the kitchen are not quite up to scratch when it comes to rules/regs/laws or general cleanliness - and the OP is a bit miffed by it - hence the photos etc...  I am sure that the saga/drama will continue - however it would be nice to know where this establishment is so as to avoid it!

Comment: Yes ready to eat.  White is for unwashed produce blue for seafood. Red for meat and yellow for chicken there is brown aswell. Not sure what the brown cutting board is for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't care if it is legit, it is unwise.

You **do not train people to use these incorrectly**, for several reasons:

- Next time they will be sloppy with other colors as well
- Someone who did not know this happened will 'lend' the board for further use with vegetables (between dishwasher cycles)
- As you correctly said, someone who did not know, will wash it at too low a temperature or too short
- You will arouse suspicion about the hygiene in your kitchen, if anyone sees this